# Read a line from a .txt file and split it to float numbers

Tags: c, file, text, io, floating-point

I have a .txt file that contains an unknown (each time) number of lines. In every line there are 4 floats separated by the space character.

My problem is that I have no clue how to separate each float from the others in each line and put it in the right place of the matrix.

This is the code I have done so far (it goes through every line for the first time so that I know the number of the lines to declare my matrix, but it only returns just the first of the four values):

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fr;

main () {

    float time, xaxis, yaxis, zaxis;
    char line[40];
    int n = 0;

    fr = fopen ("walk-after-excel.txt", "r");

    while (fgets (line, 80, fr) != NULL) {
        n++;
    }
    rewind (fr);
    printf ("%u", n);
    float values[n][4];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        values[i][0] = 0;
        values[i][1] = 0;
        values[i][2] = 0;
        values[i][3] = 0;
    }
    while (fgets (line, 80, fr) != NULL) {
        sscanf (line, "%f", &time);
        printf ("%f\n", time);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("%f, %f, %f, %f \n", values[i][0], values[i][1], values[i][2],
                values[i][3]);
    }
    printf ("%u", n);
    fclose (fr);
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to show what you have done so far yourself?

Comment: Not much, I just read through the .txt file and print it. Using code available on the internet. I'm really in darkness with what I need to do

Comment: You can use `scanf()` to read each float into a different variable. Use `malloc()` and `realloc()` to dynamically allocate an array and grow it as necessary.

Comment: There are many different ways to handle this situation but we can't go through all of them or explain everything from scratch. One possible approach is to use [`realloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) to dynamically change the size of your matrix. Another approach (if allowed) is to change the input format so that the txt file starts with the matrix size.

Comment: If it is truly only four per line, a dynamic array rooted on `float (*ar)[4]` or similar would seem appropriate. Best of luck.

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example on how to use this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few issues here:

1. In modern C, you should always specify a return type for your functions, including `main`. This means you should use `int main(void) { ... }`.
2. You specify a buffer size of 40 bytes, but you tell `fgets` that your buffer is 80 bytes, this is a huge no-no. You must never specify to functions that your buffer is bigger than it really is, or else you will encounter buffer overflows (which in the real world can become exploitable security holes). Because you are using an array type, you can simply pass `sizeof line` to `fgets`, and then it won't matter if you change the size of `line`, it will always pass the correct value to `fgets`.
3. You are only scanning in the first variable of each line, that's why you're only seeing the first value of each line.
4. You're declaring a VLA (variable length array). These are useful but in most (if not all) implementations, VLAs consume stack space, which is limited. If you try and declare a VLA that is too large, it will likely crash your application. The way around this is to use [`malloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) or [`calloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html). `calloc` is like `malloc` except that it automatically zeroes out the allocated memory for you.
5. There is no need for your `fr` variable to be global.

Since each line of the file represents a “record”, you could declare a structure, like this:

```
struct record
{
    float time;
    float xaxis;
    float yaxis;
    float zaxis;
};
```

Also, since there are an unknown number of records in the file, there are at least two ways to allocate enough memory to hold all records. One is to count all the lines in the file first, then allocate the memory based on the number of lines. This has the benefit that you will allocate exactly the right amount of memory that you need, but requires that you read the file twice. Another way is to allocate enough memory to hold a decent number of records and then “grow” this memory allocation if it turns out it wasn't big enough. This has the benefit that you only need to read the file once, but you may end up wasting memory.

You're already using the *“count number of records first, allocate later”* approach, so we just need to fix up the aforementioned issues.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct record
{
    float time;
    float xaxis;
    float yaxis;
    float zaxis;
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fr;
    char line[80];
    int n = 0;

    fr = fopen ("walk-after-excel.txt","r");
    if (fr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fr) != NULL)
    {
        n++;
    }
    rewind(fr);
    printf("%d",n); // use %d for int types

    struct record *records = calloc(n, sizeof(struct record));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof line, fr);

        sscanf(line, "%f %f %f %f", &records[i].time, &records[i].xaxis, &records[i].yaxis, &records[i].zaxis);
    }

    // records now contains all the data in the file!

    // to access the 5th line's xaxis value, use:
    printf("%f\n", records[4].xaxis);
    // (remember that arrays in C are 0-based)

    // when you are done, free the memory allocated by malloc/calloc with free()

    free(records);

    fclose(fr);
}
```

Comment: this looks really close to what I need, but it still only gets the first of the 4 floats. I added a for loop to print the records and I only get the first number from my floats. for ( i = 0; i < n; i++){
 printf("%f %f %f %f\n", records[i].time, records[i].xaxis, records[i].yaxis, records[i].zaxis);
 }

Comment: A line inside the .txt file looks like this: 205 -2,3080597 3,5524445 11,668289

Comment: I found the problem. In my .txt file floats had "," instead of ".".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.